# g++ char NULL error

Tags: c++, g++, type-conversion

I try to compile with gcc version 4.3.2 20081105 (Red Hat 4.3.2-7) (GCC) 
The input file has a const char :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "textfile.h"
...
const char * vs=NULL;
vs = textRead("myfile.file");
const char * vv = vs;
free(vs);
```

This chars vars are used into main cpp program and will be fill with text.

I use in header one function textRead to load the data from myfile.file

I got this error ( I thinking is a cast conversion ) but don't know where I make mistakes.

```
warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’
error: invalid conversion from ‘const void*’ to ‘void*’
```

first warning is about vs = textRead("myfile.file");
second error is about free(vs);

What is wrong with my code ?

Comment: What's wrong is that `free()` expects a `void *` and you're passing it a `const void *`. Which is exactly what the compiler said.

Comment: I think I need a good tutorial to understand this cpp, with g++ under linux os. Sorry I disturb the team.

Comment: You didn't disturb anyone. It's good to ask questions and learn.

Comment: I see stdio.h, stdlib.h and free... Why is this tagged c++?

Comment: The textRead take a filename ( a shader path with filename) .I use linux. The main problem is how do set all to make working. I use stdlib.h . I'm not very good with c++ and I think the tutorial i used is also make on windows os. I think c++ has another header, but I'm new in this. So sorry about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't posted what the `textRead` function looks like, so I'm assuming its signature is as follows:

```
void *textRead( char *filename );
```

`textRead` is taking the name of a file to read, it doesn't (shouldn't) need to modify the string passed to it, so change `textRead` to

```
void *textRead( char const *filename );
```

If you cannot modify the function, change your code to

```
char filename[] = "myfile.file";
vs = textRead( filename );
```

The error message about `free` is pretty self-explanatory, `free` expects a `void *` and you're passing it a `const` pointer instead. I don't see any reason why `vs` needs to be a `const char *` instead of a `char *`. Change that and the error will go away.

Also, I don't understand why you're making a copy of `vs` right before `free`ing it, but maybe you haven't posted stuff that happens in between those 2 lines.

Comment: If i use that I got this error: main.cpp:116: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘[’ token

Comment: @CatalinFestila Sorry, messed up the syntax on the array declaration. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

The first error is because your textRead() function is most likely declared thusly:

```
const char *textRead(char *)
```

Converting the string "myfile.file" (which has a type `const char *`) to `char *` automatically is deprecated. Fix it by changing textRead to accept a `const char *` instead.

The second error... well, again, see what the compiler is telling you: something is expecting a `void *` and you're passing it a `const void *`: in this case, `free` needs a `void *` pointer. You have a `const char *` which can be implicitly converted to `const void *`. But the `const void *` can't then be made into a `void *`.

Fix it by returning proper using `const` properly.